# JSON field undefined by javascript

Tags: javascript, json, mapping, undefined

I am making a map using leaflet.js and building popup bubble html from a json file. The bubbles are being populated effectively except for one new field, `pic`, which I have added to the json data. I cannot see why it is not being loaded in – it is merely rendering as 'undefined' by the browser. Can anyone suggest why it might not be being read? I think these are the important parts of the relevant files.

data.json (excerpt)

```
[
  {
    "name": "Billys",
    "address": "297 Mare Street, Hackney",
    "lat": "51.545829",
    "lng": "-0.055408",
    "pic": "billy.jpg",
    "year": 2013.0
  },
  {
    "name": "Folber",
    "address": "227 Mare Street",
    "lat": "51.544397",
    "lng": "-0.05524",
    "pic": "folber.jpg",
    "year": 2013.0
  }
]
```

map.js (excerpt)

```
function initialize() {
    var layer = new L.StamenTileLayer("holds");
    var map = new L.Map("map", {
        attributionControl: false,
        center: new L.LatLng(51.545094, -0.05609),
        zoom: 15
    });
    map.addControl(new L.Control.Attribution({
        prefix: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0">CC BY SA</a>.'
    }));

    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
    map.addLayer(layer);


    $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
        places = data;
        for (var i in places) {
            place = places[i];
            markers[i] = L.marker([place['lat'], place['lng']]).addTo(map);
            markers[i].bindPopup('<div class="popup-words"><b>' + place['name'] + "</b><br/>" + place['address'] + "</div>" + "<img alt='" + place['name'] + "' src='img/logos/" + place['pic'] + "' width='60px' height='30px' class='popup-image'/>");
        }
        updateSlider(2013);
        play();
    });
}
```

Comment: probably unrelated to your question, but as stated below you should really use a for loop or Array.forEach to iterate over an array. for( var i in places ) should be for( var i = 0 ; i < places.length ; i += 1 )

Comment: It must be something not on that code, if you just iterate the array like you're doing, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/LEMJ2/

Comment: note that places is defined as global. Is this intentional? If not put  var before it. The JSON string you posted is a valid two item array. Check with a tool like JSONLint the whole string you get back from the ajax call

Comment: it fixed itself. i'm not sure why it was happening, but it just worked in the morning. i had checked that all scripts were being refreshed, etc. I'm not sure why it happened. Thanks for your thoughts though